# Fetch & Freight robot: sudo service robot stop

Tags: ros, robot, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone.
I am newbie to ROS and my lab just have a fetch-freight robot. I was playing around with it, but get the error with rviz, so I tried to uninstall/reinstall ROS.
But now, I can not use the remote control to control the robot, as well as I tried to run the command:
"sudo service robot stop"
(http://docs.fetchrobotics.com/care_and_feeding.html)
But I got the following error.
robot: unrecognized service
Please help. Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215285/fetch-&-freight-robot:-sudo-service-robot-stop/) by [Chuong Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23343/chuong-nguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2015-08-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-08-05**:
This seems like a robot specific problem. The manufacturer might help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please contact Fetch Robotics at http://support.fetchrobotics.com/

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2015-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5